# How to rename a compiler wrapper?

Tags: openmpi

How can I name the compiler wrapper in Open MPI with a suffix of **.openmpi**? What I want is like **mpicc.openmpi** and **mpirun.openmpi**.

Answer (score 0):

In Open MPI, the compiler wrappers are all the same executable `opal_wrapper` symlinked under different names. Renaming the symlinks is not enough - you have to also rename the wrapper configuration files. If `opal_wrapper` is symlinked as `progname`, then it looks for a configuration file named `progname-wrapper-data.txt` in the `<INSTALL_BASE>/share/openmpi/` directory, where `<INSTALL_BASE>` is the base directory of Open MPI installation (usually `/usr` if Open MPI comes from a package or `/usr/local` if compiled from source). I.e. renaming `mpicc` to `mpicc.openmpi` will require you to also rename `mpicc-wrapper-data.txt` to `mpicc.openmpi-wrapper-data.txt`.

Open MPI's `mpirun` is simply a symlink to `orterun`. Renaming the symlink should be enough.

Be cautious though - if you have installed Open MPI from a package, then renaming files might fool the package manager into thinking that the package is not properly installed and it might try to "fix" it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have fixed it with your answer.